# Can I extend/apply Schengen visa while in Switzerland?

Tags: visas, schengen, switzerland

Having scanned through the website, I noticed that the questions usually ask for extension of the Schengen 'C' visa after its validity date or the 90 days are up.

For my case however, I currently have a Schengen 'C' visa that is valid till **1st July**. Now, I will be going to Switzerland for an exchange program so I have a 'D' visa as well -> for which later on I will receive a residence permit. So in effect, two Schengen visas (C and D).

To my understanding (anecdotally from others who have gone through it), the residence permit will expire when the school's official term ends (**10th July**). I, however, wish to travel a bit more in Schengen. Now since my 'C' visa expires ***1st July*** and my residence permit (regardless of its validity date) will expire on ***10th July***, if I wish to travel within Schengen after my school term.

Is it possible to:

1) Extend the 'C' visa -> I will not have used up its 90 days. I am only using up about one week for a short trip this January and my subsequent stays in Switzerland will fall under the 'D' visa *[and later the residence permit]* and hence not count towards the 90/180?

2) if 1) is not possible, is it possible to apply for another Schengen visa while I am still in Europe? Seeing that I will still have a *valid* residence permit from Switzerland, would that constitute as my being a resident? (The problem being the permit means I do not need a visa to travel but even if it's validity is 3 months away, it could expire when my school term ends.)

3) Alternatively, could I request for the residence permit to be extended seeing that the rental lease for my accommodation doesn't end till about 21st July?

Edit: Just so it's clear I am a non-EU national and I require a visa to enter Schengen zone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. A type C visa can only be extended in the case of force majeure, for humanitarian reasons, or if you can show "serious personal reasons". A general desire to tourist around will not count as "serious personal reasons", so this possibility is not open to you.
2. As far as I understand the rules, the embassy/consulate of another Schengen state in Switzerland will be *allowed* to entertain an application for a new visa from you (since even if you're not "resident" in Switzerland, you're "legally present" there), if you can justify to that consulate that it's impossible for you to apply in time from your home country -- which it is.

   However, getting such an application *approved* will probably be an uphill battle. You still need to document all of the usual visa conditions -- in particular you need to document ties to your home country that will motivate you to go there after your proposed travel ends. Seeing that whatever ties you have *don't* motivate you to return home immediately after your studies end, this could very well become a sticking point.
3. Whether you can get your D visa extended depends on Swiss national legislation, which I don't know much about. Immediately, however, it looks like this could be your best bet.

Comment: thanks for the reply :) As for point 2) i guess it could work - i have a scheduled internship back in my home country as well as documentation backing it up + return flight tickets. But yeah 3) would work however I doubt it could actually pan out seeing that I won't be studying for that 1/2 weeks which is the main reason for my being granted the permit in the first place.